# How would I convert an array of multi-dimensions into one single array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, flatten

Task: Someone has given you an array all jumbled up! Convert this multidimensional array into a single array. 
I know how to convert a 2-dimensional array into a single array. 
How would I convert a multidimensional array, into a single array?

My 2d array has an array of its own.

For example, if you were given an array like this, how would I convert this whole array into a single array?

```
arr = [[1,[2]],[3,[4]],[5,[6]],[7,[8]]] ==> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

**EX:**

```
function mergeArrays(arr) {
  var inOne = arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return a.concat(b); // works well with 2-dimension, but not this problem.
  })
  return inOne;//output is [1,Array(1),3,Array(1),1,5,Array(1),2,7,Array(1),3]
} // I need just one array. like this => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

mergeArrays([[1,[2]],[3,[4]],[5,[6]],[7,[8]]]);

// should equal arr = [[1,[2]],[3,[4]],[5,[6]],[7,[8]]] => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I guess what I'm asking is how would you convert an array of any dimension, into a single array.

I have used concat and the spread operator already, It works well if I'm dealing with a 2-dimensional array, but not if my 2-dimensional array has an array of its own.

How would you solve this?

Comment: `import flattenDeep from "lodash/flattenDeep"; flattenDeep(arr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion with reduce to return flat array.

```js
function mergeArrays(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((r, e) => r.concat(Array.isArray(e) ? mergeArrays(e) : e), [])
}

console.log(mergeArrays([[1,[2]],[3,[4]],[5,[6]],[7,[8]]]))
```